# How can I receive FM radio broadcasts on my iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, hardware

How to listen my local FM stations in my iphone 4? Like I can listen with my old Nokia phone, without using Internet, GPRS etc.

Is iPhone 4 lacking this facility?

I heard about "Pandora Radio" but it uses the Internet to run and it's also not for Indian FM channels.

In my Nokia Express Music Mobile I can listen my local FM stations without any GPRS, Internet in mobile.

Comment: Best way might be to glue a cheap FM pocket radio to the back of your iPhone's case, as the iPhone 4 does not have broadcast FM receiver circuitry built-in.

Comment: i heard some xda developer hacked htc bluetooth module to receive FM signals, i was looking same for iphone, is it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The iPhone 4 does not have a radio tuner. All it has is the appropriate cellular band, WiFi, and Bluetooth. In short, no there is no easy way to do this.

Some radio stations make apps so you can stream their content via the internet, or offer live streams. I would check out the radio station's website to see what they have available.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the info. Data plans are costly so I will keep my old Nokia phone with me if iPhone doesn't have this facility.

Comment: @Jitendra no iPhone ever had AM/FM radio, and I would bet at least 10 to 1 that no iPhone ever will. It requires a transmitter, space and mostly a bad looking antena to enable good signal. Maybe someday they decide to make one into an iPad though which is big enough to have a radio with a built in hidden antena.

Comment: @Cawas: latest ipod nano has radio receiver, with headphones used as antenna, so why would it not be possible to do in iphone?

Comment: @Peter that's big news to me! :o I never said it was impossible. I meant that since it was never done in any apple devices (as far as I knew) it was probably due to quality restrictions. There are many small radio devices, but the ones without a good antena will behave poorly. I still maintain my feeling about iPhone FM radio, but I'll have to find a better reason now. Looks like I was proven wrong deadly fast this time! :)

Comment: Note also that the iPod Nano (current and previous generation, IIRC?) is to the best of my knowledge the ONLY mobile Apple device that has had an FM receiver in it.

Comment: +1 Peter Štibraný. Cawas, 6th generation iPod Nano was launched September 1, 2010 (that's more than 1 year, 3 months ago) so that's actually OLD news!

Answer (score 2):

[Lingo](http://www.lingodab.co.uk/) provides an iPhone cover which also has a FM/DAB/DAB+ receiver and extended battery pack built-in.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a great solution: [Griffin iFM Radio Receiver](http://the-gadgeteer.com/2010/07/15/griffin-ifm-radio-receiver-for-iphoneipod-review/)

> Not everyone may need or want FM radio capability with their iPhone or iPod, but for those that do, this is a simple, straightforward solution.  Easy to install, set up and use, and according to my wife (who is the main user of this device in our household), it doesn’t seem to drain the iPhone’s battery any faster than with normal operation.  The only downsides seems to be the lack of multitask (which should be correctable through a software update) and the situation with answering phone calls.

If I get an iPhone, I will get this as well.

Answer (score 1):

It was released in 2009 and the last documentation I can find shows that the Griffin iFM Radio Receiver for iPhone and iPod did work with iOS 3. You should do more research or be OK with it not working as I can't be sure it's compatible (but don't see why it wouldn't be) with the iPhone 4 as a dock accessory.

Answer (score 0):

I use an app called [Fstream](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/fstream/id289892007?mt=8), you can make favorites of any radio station with an internet stream!

Comment: OP asks "without using Internet"

Answer (score -1):

OK. if iphone by default doesn't have FM Receiver  then this could be a good solution

http://store.apple.com/dk/product/TY512ZM/B?fnode=MTY1NDA0Mw&mco=MTM3NzE3Mjg

Comment: No. That is an FM broadcaster, not an FM receiver. The intention with that device is for you to plug that into your iPhone/iPod in order to broadcast iPod/other app music, and use a stereo (perhaps in your car or bedroom, or even living room) to listen to what your phone is playing.

Comment: Oh, then is there any device like this to use as a FM reciever. Should I delete my answer?