# How can I listen to FM radio through my iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone

My mom has an iPhone 4s. I have a iPhone 4. The radio is out of the house. She wants to listen to Garrison Keillor. Can we get radio through our iPhones?

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11639/how-can-i-receive-fm-radio-broadcasts-on-my-iphone-4 and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48561/how-can-i-receive-fm-radio-broadcast-signals-on-an-iphone-4 but the answers here are nice for their addressing the specific show that's mentioned even though the main answer is "no FM or AM radio for iPhones"

Answer (score 4):

The iPhone doesn't have native FM radio support, but you can use [the TuneIn app](http://tunein.com/mobile/), which lets you stream your local radio broadcasts on your iPhone over Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 4):

iPhone does not have an FM or AM tuner so you would need an accessory to tune in an over the air broadcast.

That said, a lot of radio shows can be listened to through apps or podcasts. Specifically for A Prarie Home Companion, you can use the [Public Radio Player](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=312880531&mt=8) app to find your local station and listen to the live stream. Note that this uses your phone's data connection, so if you are not connected to Wi-Fi, it will use data from your data plan with your wireless carrier.

Also, [Minnesota Public Radio has it's own iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mpr-radio/id291121605?mt=8) that plays most Prairie Home Companion broadcasts when they air in the normal central US time zone slot.